# How hard for US customers make payments to non-resident freelancer by wire transfer?

Tags: united-states, banking, international-transfer, contractor, wire-transfer

I'm sole proprietor from Russia. I make projects for US companies. We working fully remote via internet. I'm not US resident.

When I try to suggest wire transfer for paying my job my customers don't want to use this solution and they suggests me to use PayPal, payoneer etc third party services for making payments. But I can't use them and be legal in my country.

And of course, I suggest my clients to make B2B contract so they have legal reason for US tax service why they send money outside the country.

I know that international bank transfer is expensive and it cost about $30-40. I can care about this and include this amount to total bill. For example, project costs $1000, where $960 payment for my job and $40 for bank transfer.

But I think bank commission is not only one reason why customers suggests me to use another ways to make payment. Maybe wire transfer takes a lot of time for paperwork or something else.

Can you tell me please, is it really hard to make international wire transfer for payment my job and can I resolve this problem without using third party services?

Comment: (1) it is trivial to do, BUT, USA folks are indeed hopeless at sending wire transfers since it is not done that often there!  it's very likely they have never done it before.  (2) it is infuriatingly expensive on both ends - as you have learned, it is very impractical for amounts less than about say five thousand bucks  :/  (3) you'll have to supply or check a couple of forms, showing that you are not subject to US withholding tax

Answer (score 2):

> Can you tell me please, is it really hard to make international wire transfer for payment my job and can i resolve this problem without using third party services?

This is mostly a barrier, the form at times is quite complicated. For Russia, one has to enter "Purpose of remittance" ... at times select intermediate banks, give BIC and other details. This can become unnerving to people who are not used to it.

The other option you can try is set-up a credit card gateway and get funds via cards.

Answer (score 1):

For most major banks, wire transfers are simple, if expensive, to arrange.  For example, I can initiate an international wire transfer from my online banking portal.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for an alternative wire transfer service that will charge less. I use ofx, but note that they don't do transfers to roubles. The rate adjusts by amount being transferred and there is a $15 fee for under $5000. Upside is it is bank-to-bank. 2 days tops.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in insisting upon a proper B2B contract in any business relationship. You wish to reduce your risk and be compensated fairly.

In addition to the cost and complexity of international wire transfers, the US companies may also be considering the fact that as an international contractor in a relatively hard-to-reach jurisdiction, payments to you place the company at higher risk than payments to a domestic contractor.

By insisting upon PayPal or similar transmitters, they are reducing their internal complexity and reducing their financial exposure to unfulfilled/disputed contract terms.

Therefore, wire payments are "hard" in an internal business sense, as well as in a remittance transfer reporting sense. The internal business procedure will likely be the hardest to overcome--changing risk management is harder than filling out forms.